# DBMS integrity vs OS buffered I/O

Tags: database, security, buffer

In regards to DBMS integrity, how is an operating system's buffered I/O a threat? I have read multiple articles on why DBMS make use of their own, local cache rather than using OS buffered O/I (a good number of the reads were right here in stackoverflow), however I haven't seen any indication that the buffered O/I might pose an integrity threat to DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have found the answer I needed. It relates to transfer errors within the database effecting the integrity, "...when a piece of data is present in the destination table, but not in the source table of a relational database.", as per Talend.com article What is "Data Integrity and Why Is It Important".